# AFrame / Three.js - is there a way to get the pixel dimensions of an object3D to calculate number of pixels per meter?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, aframe

I'm pretty new to 3D programming and wonder if I could get the pixel width / height of an known object in 3D space.

My use case is the following:

I have a 2D-image that I want to put onto an `<a-image>` but only have the image size in pixels. The `<a-image>`should look as realistic as possible in the given `<a-scene>`, so I tried different things but none of them leaved me satisfied because AFrame / Three.js work with meters.

The solutions I tried:

1. calculate the ratio `pixelWidth/pixelHeight` and `pixelHeight/pixelWidth` and use them as the new image width in m.
   But the result here is that a 1024x512 a-image has the same width and height in meters as 512x256 image for example what is not what we want.
2. take the for example 1024x512 original image, divide the dimension by 1000 and use this as the new width and height in meters (this is our current approach). It gives pretty realistic results but does not seem to me like the optimal solution.

A friend of mine said I simply need a known reference object of my scene and get its width or height in pixels and in meters to calculate the pixels per meter with `widthInMeters / widthInPixels`. Then I am able to easily convert my 2D image resolution to meters which will perfectly fit in my 3d-scene.

But I did not find any way to get the pixel dimensions of an object3d. Maybe I am blind or the question is totally wrong. Someone here who can enlighten me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The number of pixels that a 3D object ocuppied on screen variates with the distance to the camera. An applied texture should scale accordingly. Use a large enough texture so it looks good at short distance. From description is unclear what the problem is. “Unsatisfied” is vague. Needs elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will update my post soon. But the that the number of pixels variates with the camera distance sounds logic..